# Perpendicular hour and minute hand

Tags: contest-math, puzzle

> Starting at $12:00$ on a $12$-hour clock, how many times will the hour and minute hands be perpendicular to each other in a 12-hour period?

Each hour there are two instances when the clock has a $90°$ angle, so (naturally) I thought that the answer would be $12•2=24$, which is wrong. I have searched some answers before this, and one of them says that "as the hours progress, the minute hand lines up 90 degrees later in the hour", but I don't see how that interferes with the $12•2$ reasoning... no matter what the hour, the two 90° cases happen within the hour, don't they?

Comment: It is easier to first look at when and how often the hands coincide (i.e. $0°$ between them). Does that happen $12$ times, once every hour?

Comment: I think your argument runs into problems for, say, the $8:00$ incident (one of which would occur at exactly $9:00$).

Comment: Count how many times it happens between 2 and 4, and you can hopefully see where you've gone wrong.

Comment: $ \times 2$ is a good idea, most hours will have two times when the hand are perpendicular ... but a more careful think about $9$ o'clock.

Comment: Notice 3:00 and 9:00 are an the cusp between two hour period.  Between $2:00$ and $3:00$ it occurs twice.  And between $3:00$ and $4:00$ it occurs twice.  But you accidently counted $3:00$ twice.  Same thing with $9:00$.  So the answer is 22.  See, the thing is the hour hand creeps up a tiny bit each time and it takes a little bit more than 30 minutes.  These extra times add up to an entire hour.  And we lose two of these events.

Comment: The hands are perpendicuar every 32 minutes or so and there are 22, not 24 of these 32 minute periods in 12 hours.

Comment: Think of it this way.  In every period from 12:00 - 1:06, 1:06- 2:12, 2:12-3:16.... (the periods between the times the hands coincide).  It happens twice.  But the hands don't coincide every hour, the coincide every hour plus a tiny amount.  Those tiny amounts will add up to a full hour, so that only happens 11 times.  Not 12.  So perps occur 22 times.  Not 24.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, let's do this the annoying way.

The minute hand moves at $360\frac {\text{degrees}}{\text{revolutions}}\frac {1 \text{revolution}}{60 \text{minutes}}=6\frac{\text{degrees}}{\text{minutes}}$

The hour hand moves at $\frac{360 degrees}{1revolution}\frac{1revolution}{12hours}\frac{1hour}{60 minute}= \frac 12 \frac{degree}{minute}$.

If a minute hand is $x$ degrees away from the hour hand how long will it take for the minute hand to become $x + 180$ degrees away from the hour hand?

Well that's a matter of solving $x + 6t = x + \frac 12t + 180$ or $t= \frac {180}{\frac {11}{2}}=\frac {360}{11}$. (Roughly $32$ minutes.)

At $3:00$ the hour hand and the minute hand are perpendicular.  The next time that will happen will be when the minute hand moves for $90$ degrees before the hour had to $90$ degrees after the hour.  That will happen in about $32$ minutes.  (At $3:32$).   Every $\frac {360}{11}$ theminute hand will move 180 degrees further than the hour hand and the hands will be perpendicular.

In a $12$ hour (or a $60*12 = 720$ minute period) this will happen $\frac {720}{\frac {360}{11}} = 22$ times.

====

Here's a better way, although it was easy to make annoying sign and logic errors if you aren't careful.

The minute hand travels $6$ degrees a minute.  ($\frac {360}{60} = 6$). The hour hand travels $.5$ degrees a minute.  ($\frac {360}{12*60} = .5$).

In a 12-hour period there are $12*60=720$ minutes.

Let's say $\theta_t = 6t$ is the angle of the minute  hand after $t; 0 \le t < 720$ minutes.  Note: it's very possible that $\theta(t) > 360$.

Let's say $\phi_t = .5t$ is the angle of the hour hand after $t$ minutes..

Obviously $\theta_t \ge \phi_t$.

$\theta_t$ and $\phi_t$ are perpendicular if $\theta_t = \phi_t + 90 + k*180$ for some non-negative integer $k$.

So we need the find out how many solutions there are to:

$6t = .5t + 90 + k*180; 0 \le t < 720$ there are.

So $t = \frac {90 + k*180}{5.5}$ will have one solution for each integer $k$.

So how many $k$ are there so that $0 \le t = \frac {90 + k*180}{5.5} < 720$ are there?

Multiply everything by $11$: $0 \le 2(90 + k*180)< 11*720$

Divide everything by $180$: $0 \le 1 + 2k < 11*4$

$-1 \le 2k < 11*4 -1$

$\frac 12  \le k < 2*11 - \frac 12$

And as $k$ is a non-negative integer $0 \le k < 22$.  There are $22$ possible $k$s which give a solution.

This also gives us the times this occurs:

$t = \frac {90 + k*180}{5.5} = \frac {180}11 + k *\frac {360}{11} \approx 16.36 + 32.72k$ (or a little more than every half-hour):

So at 12:16, 12:49, 1:22, 1:54, 2:27, 3:00, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a graph explains more than a thousand word.

On the horizontal axis I put the hours from $0$ to $12$ the purple line is the angle that the hour hand forms with the $00:00$ position.

On the vertical axis there is the angle that the minute hand forms with the $00:00$ position and is periodic since every hour the minute hand does the $360°$ round and then starts again from $0$. I have found the moments when the hands overlay and then shifting up and down by $90°$, $15$ minutes, the moments when the hands are perpendicular.

Keep in mind that the system is not isometric. To make a clearer drawing I used a $1:4$ scale. In other words four units on the $y-$axis is one hour like one unit on the $x-$axis.

If you want to know at what time the hands are perpendicular for the first time you solve the system formed by the equations of the two lines: $y=x$ the line of the minute hand and $y=\dfrac{x}{12}+\dfrac{1}{4}$ the hour hand shifted of $90°$ (=fifteen minutes). We find $\left(\frac{3}{11},\;\frac{3}{11}\right)$ which means $3/11+3/11\times 60\approx 00:16:38.2$ that is noon sixteen minutes and $38.2$ seconds.

In a similar way can be found all the other moments, changing a little the equation

hope it helps

[image]

Comment: You don't have the three times the minute hand is after the hour hand before 3 o'clock.  (2:28), (1:23), (00:18).  Or the the one time the minute hand is after the hour hand after 9 o'clock. (11:11).

Comment: @fleablood They are there! 00:18 is the first light blue on the left, 1:23 the second and 2:28 the third. The other point are fixed now. Thank you

Comment: I made a weird error when I tried to write my answer that times are when $6\theta = \frac 12(\theta \pm 90) + 60k; 0\le k < 12$ and figure $3 \le k < 9$ would have 2 solutions each but because $0 \le \theta < 360$ the rest would have only $1$ solution.   So I got 17 solutions which had to be wrong be took me a second to see why....  Similar.

Answer (score 0):

In each time interval $[n, n+1]$ hours, the minute hand is perpendicular to the hour hand twice, and there are 12 of these intervals. However, since the hands are perpendicular at 3:00 and 9:00, which each belong to two of these intervals, we overcounted by 2. Thus, the hour and minute hands are perpendicular 22 times.